# How to use let variables in rails console?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rails-console

using

```
rspec 2.6.4
rails 3.1.6
```

How to use `let` variables in rails test console?

```
1.9.3-p0 :032 > let(:user) { create(:user) }
NoMethodError: undefined method `let' for main:Object
```

Please advise, which library should be required here?

For example: below is executed in console to use `stub` methods in console.

```
require 'rspec/mocks/standalone'
```

Is it possible, to define and call `let` variables in rails console?

Comment: The short answer is no, `let` is an RSpec designation that does not work from the console. Also, `create` is presumably shorthand for `FactoryBot.create`, which is also hard to use from the console.

Comment: what would be the benefit of using `let` in rails console, as opposed to, say, simply defining a variable?

Comment: @moveson, FYI we can use `create` in console

Comment: @maxpleaner, there are multiple let variables are defined in spec and for verifying the working of each `let` variable in console, there is need to remove `let` , which is very hectic and time consuming.

Comment: @Rhunal I'm afraid what you're saying doesn't really make sense. Can you post some example of what you're trying to do and why.

Comment: @maxpleaner, why we use console? For that reason, I have to use let variables in console.

Comment: @Rhunal I'm not sure why you are running your tests in the console. are you debbugging tests? Seems like using a breakpoint would be better for that.

Comment: I can show you a way to polyfill `let` so it defines global variables instead, would that suffice?

Comment: @maxpleaner As all rspecs are having let variables, so whenever I want to debug the code in console, I need to create objects which are created using let. Every time I need to create those objects without using let in console. To make it faster I want to directly use let in console, so it will get easy if having multiple let variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are fine with `let` just creating globals, you can polyfill it like this:

```
def let(name)
  Object.send :instance_variable_set, "@#{name}", yield
  Object.send :define_method, name do
    Object.send :instance_variable_get, "@#{name}"
  end
end
```

Usage is the same as rspec:

```
irb(main):007:0> let(:foo) { 1 }
=> :foo
irb(main):008:0> foo
=> 1
```

though you really shouldn't be pasting your test code into console to debug it. It's much better to use a breakpoint tool like pry or byebug.

Comment: Thanks @max pleaner. Method is lengthy,  but works as per expectation.

Comment: Advise if there is any inbuilt method for let, so by using only require that method will reduce this work of defining let method every time when restarts console.

Comment: there is not, but if you add this method definition to a file (say let.rb) you can load it up through irb/rails console by passing the `-r ./let.rb` flag, e.g. `irb -r ./let.rb`. Do yourself a favor and look into pry or byebug though

Comment: Worth noting that Max's implementation works more like `let!` in `rspec` in a sense that it executes block eagerly - as soon as it was called. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173097/rails-rspec-difference-between-let-and-let

Answer (score 3):

`let` in `rspec` is not much more than a lazily executed and memoized method definition. If you must have in the irb you could define it like this:

```
 $ cat let.rb
 def let(sym)
   $let ||= {}

   define_method sym do
     $let[sym] ||= yield
   end
 end
```

`require './let` in irb or place it in `.irbrc` and you have your rspec-like `let`. Note, that rspec reevaluates `let` in each new example (`it` or `specify` block). Since you don't have them in irb you may need to clear your `let` cache manually (`$let = {}`) to force re-evaluation.

Comment: After defining the method in console, getting error as:                  `1.9.3-p0 :049 >     let(:user) { create_user }
NoMethodError: undefined method `define_method' for main:Object
 from (irb):45:in `let'`

Comment: In 1.9.3 you do `Object.send(:define_method, sym) do` instead. 

But really, you should just upgrade your ruby )). 1.9.3 is an ancient history.