# Quick way to make all methods in an app available in the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I understand this is probably a bad idea due to namespace collisions, but for quick and dirty inspection, is there a quick way to load methods defined across all parts of the application into the rails console so they're available without having to import them line by line or research how to import them (or recreate them)?

#### Background

Sometimes I want to do something trivial, for example play with the functionality of a method to see how it works and responds to various inputs.

Here's the most recent example - I wanted to test `let`:

```
let(:user) { User.first }
NoMethodError: undefined method `let' for main:Object
from (pry):1:in `<main>'
```

Understandably this very often results in a `NoMethodError`, which necessitates finding where that method is defined and importing it (e.g. from view helpers, a module somewhere, some built-in and the list of where that method comes from gets long). An example of having to individually `include` helpers:

```
include UsersHelper
```

And an example of individually having to research how to manually import a method: [`let`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48436445/5783745)

Answer (score 1):

Use `debugger` at the point in your code where you want to play around. It works at almost any place.